# Can we view document in another language like Norwegian using DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

We have implemented the embedded signing process and at last step we get the embedded url. So, what we want is when I click on the embedded url I want to see the document in another language for eg. Norwegian.

Is it possible that using DocuSign API we can view documents in another language like Norwegian.

Thanks and Regards

Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign will always present the documents in the same exact state as the sender supplies them in -- having DocuSign translate the documents to another language, or make any other changes to the documents is not possible.  The ability to configure "language" in DocuSign applies only to the DocuSign web console UI and other instructions that DocuSign displays to the Signer during the signing process -- not to the documents themselves.